# Python process never exits in Docker container during CircleCI workflow

Tags: python, docker, circleci

I have a `Dockerfile` that looks like this:

```
FROM python:3.6

WORKDIR /app
ADD . /app/

# Install system requirements
RUN apt-get update && \
    xargs -a requirements_apt.txt apt-get install -y

# Install Python requirements
RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pip
RUN python -m pip install -r requirements_pip.txt

# Circle CI ignores entrypoints by default
ENTRYPOINT ["dostuff"]
```

I have a CircleCI config that does:

```
version: 2.1


orbs:
  aws-ecr: circleci/aws-ecr@6.15.3


jobs:
  benchmark_tests_dev:
    docker:
      - image: blah_blah_image:test_dev
        #auth
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run:
          name: Compile and run benchmarks
          command: make bench

workflows:
  workflow_test_and_deploy_dev:
    jobs:
      - aws-ecr/build-and-push-image:
          name: build_test_dev
          context: my_context
          account-url: AWS_ECR_ACCOUNT_URL
          region: AWS_REGION
          repo: my_repo
          aws-access-key-id: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
          aws-secret-access-key: AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
          dockerfile: Dockerfile
          tag: test_dev
          filters:
            branches:
              only: my-test-branch
      - benchmark_tests_dev:
          requires: [build_test_dev]
          context: my_context
          filters:
            branches:
              only: my-test-branch
      - aws-ecr/build-and-push-image:
          name: deploy_dev
          requires: [benchmark_tests_dev]
          context: my_context
          account-url: AWS_ECR_ACCOUNT_URL
          region: AWS_REGION
          repo: my_repo
          aws-access-key-id: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
          aws-secret-access-key: AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
          dockerfile: Dockerfile
          tag: test2
          filters:
            branches:
              only: my-test-branch
```

`make bench` looks like:

```
bench:
        python tests/benchmarks/bench_1.py
        python tests/benchmarks/bench_2.py
```

Both benchmark tests follow this pattern:

```
# imports

# define constants

# Define functions/classes

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Run those tests
```

If I build my Docker container on `my-test-branch` locally, override the entrypoint to get inside of it, and run `make bench` from inside the container, both Python scripts execute perfectly and exit.

If I commit to the same branch and trigger the CircleCI workflow, the `bench_1.py` runs and then never exits. I have tried switching the order of the Python scripts in the `make` command. In that case, `bench_2.py` runs and then never exits. I have tried putting a `sys.exit()` at the end of the `if __name__ == "__main__":` block of both scripts and that doesn't force an exit on CircleCI. I the first script to be run will run to completion because I have placed logs throughout the script to track progress. It just never exits.

Any idea why these scripts would run and exit in the container locally but not exit in the container on CircleCI?

**EDIT**

I just realized "never exits" is an assumption I'm making. It's possible the script exits but the CircleCI job hangs silently after that? The point is the script runs, finishes, and the CircleCI job continues to run until I get a timeout error at 10 minutes (`Too long with no output (exceeded 10m0s): context deadline exceeded`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the `snowflake.connector` Python lib we were using has [this](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Python-connector-does-not-implement-a-destructor-method-correctly) issue where if an error occurs during an open Snowflake connection, the connection is not properly closed and the process hangs. There is also another [issue](https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-connector-python/issues/145#issuecomment-448424611) where certain errors in that lib are being logged and not raised, causing the first issue to occur silently.

I updated our snowflake IO handler to explicitly open/close a connection for every read/execute so that this doesn't happen. Now my scripts run just fine in the container on CircleCI. I still don't know why they ran in the container locally and not remotely, but I'm going to leave that one for the dev ops gods.